# Python/Feedparser: reading RSS feed fails

Tags: python, rss, urllib2, feed, feedparser

I'm using [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) to fetch RSS feed data. For most RSS feeds that works perfectly fine. However, I know stumbled upon a website where fetching RSS feeds fails ([example feed](http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/rss)). The return result does not contain the expected keys and the values are some HTML codes.

I tries simply reading the feed URL with `urllib2.Request(url)`. This fails with a `HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed` error. If I add a custom header like

```
headers = {
    'Content-type' : 'text/xml',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
}

request = urllib2.Request(url)
```

I don't get the 405 error anymore, but the returned content is a HTML document with some HEAD tags and an essentially empty BODY. In the browser everything looks fine, same when I look at "View Page Source". `feedparser.parse` also allows to set `agent` and `request_headers`, I tried various agents. I'm still not able to correctly read the XML let alone the parsed feed from `feedparse`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux: Turns out the side creates the RSS feed dynamically via Javascript -- the first time I came across that. Can your system handle this. I currently have a kind of working solution using PhantomJS. I will probably provide an answer soon based on this.

Comment: No they don't generate the feed via JS :) (I'm not even sure that's possible!). See below for an answer... and yes, Superfeedr is able to handle that pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

So, this feed yields a `405` error when the client making the request does not use a `User-Agent`. Try this:

```
$ curl 'http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/rss' -H 'User-Agent: hum' -o /dev/null -D- -s
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 15:48:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 24616
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

While without the UA, you get:

```
$ curl 'http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/rss' -o /dev/null -D- -s
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 15:49:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I got around the 405 error by setting the header. But neither using cURL or using Python request I get an XML document as I would expect from an RSS feed. Only some almost empty HTML document. Could you post the cURL that actually outputs the XML?

Comment: That's what I did! (remove -o /dev/null) and you'll see the full XML!

Comment: Uh, doesn't work for me. If I do `curl 'http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/rss' -H 'User-Agent: hum' -D- -s` I get at minimal HTML document with body `<body><div id="distil_ident_block">&nbsp;</div></body>`.